# How to fix "Unsafe interpretation of method return type" in Eclipse null annotation analysis

Tags: java, eclipse, null

Using Eclipse 2019-12.

I'm defining a method like this:

```java
public static <T> T execute(@NonNull Supplier<T> action) {
  return action.get();
}
```

Now, if I do this:

```
public @NonNull String foo() { return ""; }

public String doSomething() {
  return MyClass.execute(() -> foo());
}
```

Eclipse shows an info/warning message on `doSomething` body saying:

```
Unsafe interpretation of method return type as '@NonNull' based on substitution 'T=@NonNull String'. Declaring type 'MyClass' doesn't seem to be designed with null type annotations in mind
```

So, I can understand that having `MyClass.execute(Supplier)` returning `T` and passing a `Supplier<T>` where `T` is `@NonNull` doesn't necessarily mean that the return type is also `@NonNull`, because in general `MyClass.execute(Supplier)` could be implemented like this:

```java
public static <T> T execute(Supplier<T> action) {
  if(action.getClass().getSimpleName().startsWith("a"))
    return null;
  return action.get();
}
```

in which case, even if the specified `Supplier`s `T` type variable is `@NonNull`, `MyClass.execute(Supplier)` still returns `null` in some cases (and `Map.get(Object)` is a concrete example, where it can return `null` if the specified key is missing, even if the `Map` is defined to have a `@NonNull` value type).

But now, since `MyClass.execute(Supplier)` is under my control, I would like to understand if there's a way to write it to express without ambiguities that its return type is non-null if the specified `Supplier` has a `@NonNull` return value, while it's nullable if the specified `Supplier` has a `@Nullable` return value.

Also, it's not clear to me why this does NOT generate the above info/warning:

```
public String doSomething() {
  return MyClass.execute(() -> "");
}
```

that is, I simply inlined the `foo()` method call in the above example.

Comment: It does not make sense to use annotation-based null analysis only partially. Make sure, your Eclipse is not outdated and not to ignore _Unsafe conversion of annotated parameterized type to less-annoted type_ problems.

Comment: How do you conclude that I'm using annotation-based null analysis only partially? I don't think it's the case here, at least not on purpose. I'm using Eclipse 2019-12, not the latest version but quite recent. I don't find the option you mention among those regarding annotation-based null analysis.

Comment: Without `@NonNullByDefault` (e.g. on package level), everything that goes into a method and comes out must be annotated, otherwise it is only partially annotated (like in your examples). In Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15) annotation-based null analysis has been improved and the mentioned option has been added (see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.15/jdt.php#null-legacy-interface), [this blog post for details](https://objectteams.wordpress.com/2020/02/06/interfacing-null-safe-code-with-legacy-code/) and [watch my video showing this in action](https://youtu.be/XoUvOTiVaDc?t=150)).

Comment: @howlger I will give 2020-03 a try, thanks, still I don't understand how I should change my code. `public static <@Nullable T> T execute(Supplier<T> action)` and `public static <@NonNull T> T execute(Supplier<T> action)` would be both wrong, because what I would like to express is that the return type `T` is nullable or not depending on whether the `T` in `Supplier<T>` is itself nullable or not. Which is the essence of generic methods.

Comment: Update to 2020-06 and you will see that your question no longer applies. I just checked that and no info/warning message on `doSomething` is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message was shown incorrectly in Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14) and before.

In Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15) annotation-based null analysis has been improved. A new check (*Unsafe conversion of annotated parameterized type to less-annoted type*) has been added and several fixes have been made that also affect your example.

There are no messages shown in the following code anymore:

```
public static <T> T execute(@NonNull Supplier<T> action) {
    return action.get();
}

public @NonNull String foo() {
    return "";
}

public @NonNull String doSomething() {
    return MyClass.execute(() -> foo());
}
```

But if you change `foo()` to return a `@Nullable` value, in the line `return Foo.execute(() -> foo());` the following problem is correctly shown:

```
Null type safety (type annotations): The expression of type 'String' needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@NonNull String'
```

For the new *Unsafe conversion of annotated parameterized type to less-annoted type* option see:

- [Eclipse 4.15 - New and Noteworthy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.15/jdt.php#null-legacy-interface)
- [Blog post *Interfacing null-safe code with legacy code* by Stephan Herrmann](https://objectteams.wordpress.com/2020/02/06/interfacing-null-safe-code-with-legacy-code/)
- [My video showing this in action](https://youtu.be/XoUvOTiVaDc?t=150)

Comment: So I was cheated by a buggy implementation in Eclipse 2019-12. In Eclipse 2020-06, indeed, I see a much more reasonable behaviour of annotation-based null analysis. Thanks for your help to track this down. Still I don't understand why someone downvoted my question, after all I was not crazy...